# Screenreader doesn't read full page

Tags: html, nvda

I'm using NVDA screen reader to read the content of the page, but unfortunately it does not work as intended. Screen reader does not read the full page (i.e. it doesnt read the labels). All the contents are in .twig file.
Here's the jsFiddle and a snippet.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/juvysx6z/

```html
 <div class="buttons-block block-index">
             <h3>NVDA doesnt read this header</h3>
             <h6>This one as well</h6>
      </div>
```

It seems a bit weird, because some parts of the page are just omitted, another example here:

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="large-8 columns">
            <section>
                <header class="clean">
                    <h2 style="color: #004E9D">Does not read it</h2>
                </header>
             </section>
        </div>
</div>
```

Could anybody help me with this one? The worst thing is that I don't know where to find reason why it's not working. I'm totally stuck.